# changing the appearance of feature.vector in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I am transitioning my code from using a marker layer to a vector layer.  I am having problems displaying markers on the map as a Feature.Vector class (before I used simply the Feature class).

Specifically, I cannot figure out how to display each feature with a distinct image that I choose.  I've seen some examples of how to change the style of a feature in general using stylemaps, but I have not seen a way to directly set the image of a feature.

This seems to be a simple problem but I have not yet found the solution.  I am currently trying to use a style property:

```
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(ll.lon, ll.lat), {externalGraphic: "http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png"});
```

However, this just results in the normal default icon (an orange circle).

Setting data.icon of the feature and creating a marker equally does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a vector layer to display markers?

Comment: Alex, I'm changing to a vector layer because it has more features - I'm going to add features like clustering and rotation of features on the map using the geometry class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you put placeholders in the layer style which get populated by the features attributes.

```js
var style = OpenLayers.Util.extend({
    externalGraphic : "${icon}",
    pointRadius     : 15
}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);

var layer   = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Simple Geometry", { style: style }),
    point   = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(ll.lon, ll.lat),
    feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, { icon: "icon.png" });

layer.addFeature(feature);
```

Comment: if you neglect PointRadius, the externalGraphic does not show at all.  thanx, saved me.  UPVOTED!